# How can I determine whether my UIButton's event is Touch Down?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

How can I determine whether my button's event is Touch Down?

I want to do a function like this:

```
if(users click on touchdown event)
{

NSLog(@"a");

}

else if(users click on touchupinside event)
{

NSLog(@"b");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eather you set two different IBAction methods in the InterfaceBuilder or you set two different targets via:

`- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents`

in your code while creating the button.

Answer (score 1):

You "find out" by letting the button tell you when the event happens.

Add a method (or methods) like this:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonClick:(id)sender;
```

In Interface Builder, attach the method(s) to the events you're interested in.

You create a separate method for each type of event if you want different behavior for a TouchDown as opposed to TouchUpInside.

Answer (score 0):

you attach each unique event to its own IBAction